# Sqlldr to upload data doesn't work correctly and loads data into different columns

Tags: shell, scripting, sql-loader

I am trying to load data from a csv to oracle table but it doesn't seem to work correctly.
I am having issue in data mapping with columns. Data is getting into the wrong columns in the table and due to this the whole load is not successful.

Thanks,
Aditya

I tried to upload the sample data file with the shell script and the data loads into wrong columns and therefore fails due to data type mismatch.

Table details

```
CATEGORY                 VARCHAR2(50)   
START_DATE               DATE           
USER_ID                  NUMBER         
FIRST_NAME               VARCHAR2(50)   
LAST_NAME                VARCHAR2(50)   
FULL_NAME                VARCHAR2(100)  
USERNAME                 VARCHAR2(30)   
BUSINESS_TITLE           VARCHAR2(1000) 
MANAGER_ID               VARCHAR2(30)   
MANAGER                  VARCHAR2(100)  
USER_LOCATION            VARCHAR2(100)  
ROLE_ID                  NUMBER         
ROLE_NAME                VARCHAR2(100)  
REG_TEMP                 VARCHAR2(50)   
REG_REGION               VARCHAR2(100)  
TG                       VARCHAR2(100)  
SUBTEAM                  VARCHAR2(100)  
FTE                      NUMBER(8)      
EMPLID                   VARCHAR2(30)   
EMPL_STATUS              VARCHAR2(30)   
DEPTNAME                 VARCHAR2(100)  
HIRE_DT                  DATE           
TERMINATION_DT           DATE           
SKILL_NAME               VARCHAR2(1000) 
PROJECT_ID               VARCHAR2(50)   
CREATED_BY_USER_ID       VARCHAR2(30)   
DEMAND_START             DATE           
DEMAND_END               DATE           
PROJECT_TITLE            VARCHAR2(500)  
PROJECT_TYPE             VARCHAR2(200)  
PROJECT_STATUS           VARCHAR2(100)  
PROJECT_KEY              VARCHAR2(100)  
EMPLID1                  VARCHAR2(30)   
MANAGER_NAME             VARCHAR2(100)  
MANAGER_ID1              VARCHAR2(30)   
LVL                      NUMBER         
JIRA_DOMAIN              VARCHAR2(200)  
DEPTID                   VARCHAR2(25)   
JOB_TITLE                VARCHAR2(200)  
USER_ROLE                VARCHAR2(100)  
PREFERRED_NAME           VARCHAR2(100)
```

shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set the Oracle environment variables
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/software/test/oracle
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# Set the Oracle connection details
#export ORACLE_SID=<sid>
export ORACLE_USER=<uname>
export ORACLE_PASSWORD=<pwd>
export ORACLE_HOST=<host>
export ORACLE_PORT=1521
export ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME=<sname>

#log files
ldlogfile=rm_data_load.log
ldprcs_fl=rm_data_log.log

# Set the CSV file path and table name
CSV_FILE=/u/mmanogya/baz.csv
TABLE_NAME=<tablename>
# Create the control file for SQL*Loader
CONTROL_FILE=sqlldr_control.ctl

# Run SQL*Loader to load the CSV file
echo sqlldr $ORACLE_USER/$ORACLE_PASSWORD@$ORACLE_HOST:$ORACLE_PORT/$ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME control=$CONTROL_FILE
sqlldr $ORACLE_USER/$ORACLE_PASSWORD@$ORACLE_HOST:$ORACLE_PORT/$ORACLE_SERVICE_NAME control=$CONTROL_FILE log=$ldlogfile >$ldprcs_fl 2>&1
```

control file

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE, SILENT=(HEADER,FEEDBACK,DISCARDS,PARTITIONS))
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'baz.csv'
INSERT
INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
optionally enclosed by '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
CATEGORY char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',  
START_DATE DATE "YYYY-MM-DD", 
USER_ID,       
FIRST_NAME char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
LAST_NAME char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"', 
FULL_NAME char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',  
USERNAME char,
BUSINESS_TITLE char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
MANAGER_ID char,
MANAGER char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
USER_LOCATION char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
ROLE_ID,
ROLE_NAME char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
REG_TEMP char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
REG_REGION char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',  
TG char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
SUBTEAM char,
FTE,
EMPLID char,
EMPL_STATUS char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
DEPTNAME char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
Y FILLER,
Z FILLER,
SKILL_NAME char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
PROJECT_ID char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
CREATED_BY_USER_ID char,
A FILLER,
B FILLER,
PROJECT_TITLE char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
PROJECT_TYPE char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
PROJECT_STATUS char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
PROJECT_KEY char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
EMPLID1 char,
MANAGER_NAME char,
MANAGER_ID1 char,
LVL,
JIRA_DOMAIN char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
DEPTID char,
JOB_TITLE char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
USER_ROLE char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
PREFERRED_NAME char OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
)
```

error log

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Wed May 17 23:38:00 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   sqlldr_control.ctl
Data File:      baz.csv
  Bad File:     baz.bad
  Discard File:  none specified
 
 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Direct
Silent options: FEEDBACK and DISCARDS

Table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: INSERT
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
CATEGORY                            FIRST     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
START_DATE                           NEXT     *   ,  O(") DATE YYYY-MM-DD      
USER_ID                              NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
FIRST_NAME                           NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
LAST_NAME                            NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
FULL_NAME                            NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
USERNAME                             NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
BUSINESS_TITLE                       NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
MANAGER_ID                           NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
MANAGER                              NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
USER_LOCATION                        NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
ROLE_ID                              NEXT     4           INTEGER              
ROLE_NAME                            NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
REG_TEMP                             NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
REG_REGION                           NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
TG                                   NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
SUBTEAM                              NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
FTE                                  NEXT     4           PACKED DECIMAL (7, 2)
EMPLID                               NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
EMPL_STATUS                          NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
DEPTNAME                             NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
Y                                    NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
  (FILLER FIELD)
Z                                    NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
  (FILLER FIELD)
SKILL_NAME                           NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
PROJECT_ID                           NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
CREATED_BY_USER_ID                   NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
A                                    NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
  (FILLER FIELD)
B                                    NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
  (FILLER FIELD)
PROJECT_TITLE                        NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
PROJECT_TYPE                         NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
PROJECT_STATUS                       NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
PROJECT_KEY                          NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
EMPLID1                              NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
MANAGER_NAME                         NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
MANAGER_ID1                          NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
LVL                                  NEXT     4           INTEGER              
JIRA_DOMAIN                          NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
DEPTID                               NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
JOB_TITLE                            NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
USER_ROLE                            NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            
PREFERRED_NAME                       NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER            

Record 1: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 3: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 4: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 5: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 6: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 7: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 8: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 9: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 10: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 11: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 12: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 13: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 14: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 15: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 16: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 17: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 18: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 19: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 20: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 21: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 22: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 23: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 24: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 25: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 26: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 27: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 28: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 29: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 30: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 31: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 32: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 33: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 34: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 35: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 36: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 37: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 38: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 39: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 40: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 41: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 42: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 43: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 44: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 45: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 46: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 47: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 48: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 49: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 50: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Record 51: Rejected - Error on table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP, column FTE.
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested


MAXIMUM ERROR COUNT EXCEEDED - Above statistics reflect partial run.

Table PPM_RM_REPORTING_TMP:
  0 Rows successfully loaded.
  51 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

  Date cache:
   Max Size:      1000
   Entries :         3
   Hits    :        49
   Misses  :         0

Bind array size not used in direct path.
Column array  rows :    5000
Stream buffer bytes:  256000
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records rejected:        51
Total logical records discarded:        0
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader main thread:        1
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader load thread:        1

Run began on Wed May 17 23:38:00 2023
Run ended on Wed May 17 23:38:37 2023

Elapsed time was:     00:00:37.49
CPU time was:         00:00:00.16
```

Data Set Below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make this change to your control file:

```
FTE  decimal external,
```

Actually define all NUMBER columns decimal external.